# Inserting PricebookEntry from apex throwing error

Tags: apex, pricebook, dmlexception, pricebookentry

I have Written a trigger to  insert a pricebookentry based on creation of product. I am using custom pricebooks in my org. But I couldn't able to insert pricebookentry and apex is throwing following error.

> Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger trgProduct caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: trgProduct: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this product: []: Class.PriceBookEntryHandler.InsertPriceBkEntry: line 41, column 1

```
    List<PricebookEntry> pbEntries = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
    pbe.Pricebook2Id = priceBookMap.get(product.UM_Buying__c).Id;
    System.debug('pbe.Pricebook2Id ' + pbe.Pricebook2Id);
    pbe.Product2Id = product.Id;
    //pbe.UseStandardPrice = true;
    pbe.UnitPrice = calculateUnitPrice(product);
    pbEntries.add(pbe);
    if(product.UM_Buying__c == 'MT'){
        PricebookEntry pbeYD = new PricebookEntry();
        pbeYD.Pricebook2Id = priceBookMap.get('YD').Id;
        pbeYD.Product2Id = product.Id;
        //pbeYD.UseStandardPrice = true;
        pbeYD.UnitPrice = calculateUnitPrice(product);            
        pbEntries.add(pbeYD);
    }
    else if(product.UM_Buying__c == 'YD'){
        PricebookEntry pbeMT = new PricebookEntry();
        pbeMT.Pricebook2Id = priceBookMap.get('MT').Id;
        pbeMT.Product2Id = product.Id;
        //pbeMT.UseStandardPrice = true;
        pbeMT.UnitPrice = calculateUnitPrice(product);
        pbEntries.add(pbeMT);
    }
    System.debug('pbEntries ' + pbEntries);
    insert pbEntries;
```

Comment: Post your Trigger Code.

Comment: You have to insert a pricebook entry linked to the standard pricebook before being able to add a pricebook entry to an another pricebook.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/get-standard-price-without-query-seealldata-cannot-be-true/148587#148587) where a similar question was asked regarding the same error.

Comment: @TSmith That is to write test class.

Comment: @HSdev Post Updated

Comment: the error message seems self-explanatory: *No standard price defined for this product*

Comment: @Novarg `pbe.UseStandardPrice = true;`

Comment: what about the other two?

Comment: @Novarg i have added that to other two also, but same issue.

Comment: does your `product` have a price?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52004/discussion-between-srujan-sujju-and-novarg).

Comment: This is a very common error and check this pdf to understand how the standardprice is used even for custom pricebooks : https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001OdbFAAS